# problem with flutter_facebook_auth building

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

i am facing a problem while building flutter app while using flutter_facebook_auth v3.3.3 with this message but i didn't find any solution

Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find core-1.3.2.jar (androidx.core:core:1.3.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.3.2/core-1.3.2.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
  The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
  Building plugin flutter_facebook_auth...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'flutter_facebook_auth'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: The plugin flutter_facebook_auth could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)